# How to add custom payload to ConsumeContext?

Tags: masstransit

I try to add custom payload to ConsumeContext like this

```
public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<Message1> context)
{
    context.GetOrAddPayload(() => new Payload());
    return context.Publish(new Message2()); 
}
```

And expect to get this payload in Message2 consumer. But theere is no such payload in context;

```
public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<Message2> context)
{
    Payload payload;
    context.TryGetPayload<Payload>(out payload);
}
```

payload always null.
So can I add my cusom payload to the context and how to do it correctly? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Payloads added to the `ConsumeContext` are valid for the current message only, and are not persistent. They are used by middleware components to save data and/or provide data for downstream middleware components or services (such as consumers, sagas, etc.) that are consuming messages.

If you need to save data between messages, consider using a saga correlated by a common identifier so that the messages are delivered to the same saga instance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.